# CWM: Almost any rom I try to install returns "(Status 0)" [HTC One GSM]

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, htc-one

CWM version: 6.0.4.3 touch

I tried to update my CM 10.2 to 11, but I always run into this error when installing a zip from SD card:

```
E:Error in /data/media/0/[filename].zip
(Status 0)
Installation aborted.
```

This happens for every rom I try to install, *except* a Kitkat AOSP rom I tried.

Even the 10.2 Rom I still had around on the card threw an error, but a different one.

I can't remember what exactly, but it looked like it couldn't match my phone's type (`m7`) to `m7`  or `m7ul`

I think my phone somehow forgot that it is an `m7`

Anyone got an idea how I can install roms again?

Comment: Have you tried reflashing CWM? Or flashing a different recovery? Also check whether you have data and system unmounted (In CWM you go to "Mount and Storage"). Oh and also flash CWM 6.0.4.6 because I'm sure you need newer updates of CWM to flash newer ROMs. Just tell me what (if any) of these work and I will write out the answer.

Comment: Thanks to your comment on "updating" CWM I found the problem. For whatever reason, I the `m7att` version instead of the GSM/general `m7` version installed before. Which explains why it couldn't match the `m7` version of the roms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I had the `m7att` version of CWM installed. Must have misclicked when downloading.

Updated CWM to the generic `m7` version and rom flashing works again.